# Can JAXB create a 'read only' class property?

Tags: java, xml, jaxb

Is there a way to have jaxb create only a getter(no setter) for a class property generated from an element tag in the xsd file(i.e. an element of type xs:integer)? How about making a primitive type property const(i.e. one that is generated from an element of type xs:int)?

Answer (score 1):

The normal practise is to convert your JAXB generated objects into properly defined domain model classes. That way you have full control over how the model classes behave in your code and if the XSD changes you dont get a lot of places in your code that breaks. You only have to update your "converter" class as that should be the only place where you're relying on the JAXB generated classes